# How can I get list values that meet specific conditions?

Tags: arrays, list, numpy, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm an introductory member of Python.
I are implementing code to organize data with Python.
I have to extract a value that meets only certain conditions out of the numerous lists.
It seems very simple, but it feels too difficult for me.

First, let me explain with the simplest example

```
solutions
Out[73]: 
array([[ 2.31350622e-04, -1.42539948e-02, -7.17361833e-02,
         2.17545418e-01, -3.38251827e-01,  1.88254191e-01],
       [ 4.23523963e-82, -9.48255372e-81,  5.22018863e-80,
        -1.11271010e-79,  1.03507672e-79, -3.55573390e-80],
       [ 2.31350597e-04, -1.42539951e-02, -7.17361800e-02,
         2.17545409e-01, -3.38251817e-01,  1.88254187e-01],
       [ 2.58309722e-02, -6.21550000e-01,  3.41867505e+00,
        -7.53828444e+00,  7.09091365e+00, -2.39409614e+00],
       [ 2.31350606e-04, -1.42539950e-02, -7.17361809e-02,
         2.17545411e-01, -3.38251820e-01,  1.88254188e-01],
       [ 1.14525725e-02, -3.25174709e-01,  2.11632584e+00,
        -5.16113713e+00,  5.12508331e+00, -1.78380602e+00],
       [ 9.75839726e-03, -3.08729919e-01,  2.26983591e+00,
        -6.16462170e+00,  6.76409438e+00, -2.55992476e+00],
       [ 1.13190092e-03, -6.72042220e-02,  7.10413638e-01,
        -2.39952623e+00,  2.94849402e+00, -1.18046338e+00],
       [ 5.24406689e-03, -1.86240596e-01,  1.36500589e+00,
        -3.61106144e+00,  3.75606312e+00, -1.34699295e+00]])

coeff
Out[74]: 
array([[ 1.03177808e-04, -6.35700011e-03, -3.19929208e-02,
         9.70209594e-02, -1.50853634e-01,  8.39576506e-02,
         4.45980248e-01],
       [ 5.13911499e-83, -1.15062991e-81,  6.33426960e-81,
        -1.35018220e-80,  1.25598048e-80, -4.31459067e-81,
         1.21341776e-01],
       [ 1.03177797e-04, -6.35700027e-03, -3.19929194e-02,
         9.70209556e-02, -1.50853630e-01,  8.39576490e-02,
         4.45980249e-01],
       [ 4.26209161e-03, -1.02555298e-01,  5.64078896e-01,
        -1.24381145e+00,  1.16999559e+00, -3.95024121e-01,
         1.64999272e-01],
       [ 1.03177801e-04, -6.35700023e-03, -3.19929198e-02,
         9.70209566e-02, -1.50853631e-01,  8.39576495e-02,
         4.45980248e-01],
       [ 2.27512838e-03, -6.45980810e-02,  4.20421959e-01,
        -1.02529362e+00,  1.01813129e+00, -3.54364724e-01,
         1.98656535e-01],
       [ 1.42058482e-03, -4.49435521e-02,  3.30432790e-01,
        -8.97418681e-01,  9.84687293e-01, -3.72662657e-01,
         1.45575629e-01],
       [ 2.46722650e-04, -1.46486353e-02,  1.54850246e-01,
        -5.23029411e-01,  6.42688990e-01, -2.57307904e-01,
         2.17971950e-01],
       [ 1.30617191e-03, -4.63880878e-02,  3.39990392e-01,
        -8.99429225e-01,  9.35545685e-01, -3.35503798e-01,
         2.49076135e-01]])
```

In a matrix defined as 'numpy', called 'solutions', each row represents 'solutions[0]','solutions[1]', 'solutions[i]'... In addition, the 'coeff' is also defined as 'numpy', and the 'coeff[0]','coeff[1]','coeff[i]'... is matched to 'solutions[0]','solutions[1]','solutions[i]'...

What I want at this time is to find specific 'solution[i]' and 'coeff[i]' where all elements of solutions[i] are less than 10^-10 and all elements of coeff[i] are greater than 10^-3.

I wonder if there is an appropriate code to extract a list array in a situation that meets more than one condition. I'm a Python initiator, so please excuse me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished using advanced indexing:

```
solution_valid = np.all(solutions < 10e-10, axis=1)
coeff_valid = np.all(coeff > 1e-3, axis=1)
both_valid = coeff_valid & solution_valid

valid_solutions = solutions[both_valid]
valid_coeffs = coeff[both_valid]
```

but perhaps you mean that the **absolute value** should be greater or below a certain threshold?

```
solution_valid = np.all(np.abs(solutions) < 10e-10, axis=1)
coeff_valid = np.all(np.abs(coeff) > 1e-3, axis=1)
both_valid = coeff_valid & solution_valid

valid_solutions = solutions[both_valid]
valid_coeffs = coeff[both_valid]
```

Comment: You're really the best. It helped me a lot. Thank you.